# How do I decide number of mappers for camus?

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, camus

I just started with Camus.

I am planning to run Camus, every one hour. We get around ~`80000000` messages every hour and average message size is `4KB` (we have a single topic in Kafka).

I first tried with `10` mappers, it took ~2hours to copy one hour's data and it created 10 files with ~7GB size.

Then I tried `300` mappers, it brought down the time to ~1 hour. But it created 11 files. Later, I tried with `150` mappers and it took ~30 minutes.

So, how do I choose the number of mappers in this? Also, I want to create more files in hadoop as one size is growing to 7GB. What configuration do I have to check?

Answer (score 0):

It should ideally be equal or less than the kafka partitions you have , in your topic .

That means , for better throughput you topic should have more partitions and same number of camus mappers

Answer (score -1):

I have found best answer in this [article](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces)

The number of maps is usually driven by the number of **DFS blocks** in the input files. It causes people to adjust their DFS block size to adjust the number of maps.

The right level of parallelism for maps seems to be around **10-100 maps/node**, although we have taken it up to **300** or so for very cpu-light map tasks.

It is best if the maps take at least a minute to execute.

All depends on the power of CPU you have, the type of application - **IO Bound** (heavy read/write) Or **CPU bound** ( heavy processing) and number of nodes in your Hadoop cluster.

Apart from setting number of mappers and reducers at global level, override those values at **Job** level depending on data to be processing needs of the Job.

And one more thing in the end : If you think **Combiner** reduces the IO transfers between **Mapper** and **Reducer**, use it effectively in combination with **Partitioner**